# AWS DynamoDB gives strange ResourceNotFoundException but region is explicitly set

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have the region of my DynamoDB explicitly defined as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.TABLE_REGION });

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: '2012-08-10', region: process.env.TABLE_REGION });
```

where process.env.TABLE_REGION refers to the region I have defined.  This might seem a little redundant but I keep finding answers that say "the wrong region is specified' when it seems pretty clear to me that isn't the case here.

The problem is, occasionally when I update the table (usually several hundred simultaneous PUTs) I *sometimes* get a ResourceNotFoundException with the message "Requested Resource Not Found".  The vast majority of the PUTs work, just the occasional one doesn't.  I would assume it's some kind of throttling message but I can't find any documentation that supports that use of the exception.  Also, my database capacity is well within target values.

What is going on?  This problem makes it almost impossible to handle large uploads as they fail randomly.  I understand that batch uploads are not guaranteed to work and require logic to retry, but my understanding is that individual requests should always work.  And the error message makes no sense; the resource is where it has always been.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

Some code samples (a little bit difficult to summarize/replicate as the script is rather large, but will do my best).  This is only pseudo-code at best; I should point out that the code has gone through many iterations but the result is the same.  Thinking that the problem is more fundamental than simply identifying errors in the code.  Also, it *often* works, just occasionally doesn't:

Also, these are PUTs.  When I say "update" the table I'm not being very accurate, more in the sense of "make changes to" the table, but more precisely "make inserts to".

```
const posts = [...];

const addPost = async ({ post }) => {
  await dynamodb.put({
      TableName: tableName,
      Item: {
          PartitionKey: organizationId + '-POST',
          SortKey: post.creationTime + '--' + post.id,
          ...post
      }
  }).promise();
};

const addAllPosts = async ({ sum = [], posts, index = 0 }) => {
  if (posts[index] === undefined) {
    await Promise.all(sum);

    return;
  }

  const post = posts[index];

  sum.push(addPost({ post }));

  if (sum.length === 300) {
    await Promise.all(sum);
    sum = undefined;
  } 

  await addAllPosts({ posts, sum, index: index + 1 });
};

await addAllPosts({ posts });
```

The main idea is that I want to make inserts in batches of no more than 300, so I can anticipate db write units.

FULL ERROR:

It only happens occasionally, but when it does of course it breaks everything:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection: ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found",
        "    at process.on (/var/runtime/index.js:37:15)",
        "    at process.emit (events.js:198:13)",
        "    at process.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at emitPromiseRejectionWarnings (internal/process/promises.js:119:20)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:69:34)"
    ],
    "reason": {
        "errorType": "ResourceNotFoundException",
        "errorMessage": "Requested resource not found",
        "code": "ResourceNotFoundException",
        "stack": [
            "ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found",
            "    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
            "    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)",
            "    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
            "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
            "    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
            "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)",
            "    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
        ],
        "message": "Requested resource not found",
        "time": "2019-09-23T23:22:54.784Z",
        "requestId": {redacted},
        "statusCode": 400,
        "retryable": false,
        "retryDelay": 3.7761727886367558
    },
    "promise": {}
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code you can paste here that I can run to look at this for you? I want to see the code is why. You say at one point you are updating, but at another it is puts. Which is it or both?

Also, please tag the SDK language you are using so you get get fellow developers in on helping with your question. Looks like you are using javascript, but do not want to assume.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Please see edits

Comment: Do you happen to have the full Error JSON that'd be kicked out? I have tried to recreate a throttling event, but the only error I can get to happen is the real throttle error code "ProvisionedThroughputExceededException".

Comment: Thanks again, see edit

Comment: I would catch that exception and then print out a few key pieces of data such as the value of `tableName` and the value of process.env.TABLE_REGION. The symptoms certainly suggest a put against a non-existent table (or in the wrong region).

Comment: Make sure table name is exactly same as actual DynamoDB table (even upper and lower case)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think any of the PUTs would have worked had I mis-spelled the tablename or had the wrong region. This error only happens occasionally...

Comment: if thats the case can you check if your session tokens are not getting expired. I would have them setup within DDB client initialization code and see if that helps

Comment: If that were the case, which I'm skeptical, I would expect an access denied error.... will look into all the same

Comment: when i log `process.env` i did not find any field `TABLE_REGION` . Instead i found `AWS_REGION`

Comment: It's been a few months but I think I just happened to call mine TABLE_REGION while yes, the default is AWS_REGION. Definitely wasn't a region issue though.  Not sure I ever got to the bottom of this; ended up writing logic just to retry failures.